# How can I loop through an IEnumerable<string> and create another IEnumerable<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, projection

I have this code that I use to process strings in the `IEnumerable<string>` text

```
foreach (var line in text)
{
    var newLine = "";
    var ln = line.TrimStart(' ');
    var colon = line.IndexOf(":");
    if (colon != -1)
    {
        if (ln.StartsWith("adj")) newLine = "j 1" + line.Substring(colon);
        else if (ln.StartsWith("adv")) newLine = "d 1" + line.Substring(colon);
        else if (ln.StartsWith("n")) newLine = "n 1" + line.Substring(colon);
        else if (ln.StartsWith("v")) newLine = "v 1" + line.Substring(colon);
    }
    else
    {
        newLine = line;
    }
}
```

Right now it just loops through the `IEnumerable` but what I would like is for it to create another `IEnumerable<string>` where the string is just the contents of `newLine.Trim()`

Can anyone give me advide on how I can do this?

Comment: You're looking for `.Select()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var result = text.Select(line =>
    {
        var newLine = "";
        var ln = line.TrimStart(' ');
        var colon = line.IndexOf(":");
        if (colon != -1)
        {
            if (ln.StartsWith("adj")) newLine = "j 1" + line.Substring(colon);
            else if (ln.StartsWith("adv")) newLine = "d 1" + line.Substring(colon);
            else if (ln.StartsWith("n")) newLine = "n 1" + line.Substring(colon);
            else if (ln.StartsWith("v")) newLine = "v 1" + line.Substring(colon);
        }
        else
        {
            newLine = line;
        }
        return newLine.Trim();
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Just `yield return` the value inside the `foreach` loop.

Make your method return `IEnumerable<string>` and you will be set:

```
public IEnumerable<string> MethodX(string[] text)
{
    foreach (var line in text)
    {
        var newLine = "";
        var ln = line.TrimStart(' ');
        var colon = line.IndexOf(":");
        if (colon != -1)
        {
        if (ln.StartsWith("adj")) newLine = "j 1" + line.Substring(colon);
            else if (ln.StartsWith("adv")) newLine = "d 1" + line.Substring(colon);
            else if (ln.StartsWith("n")) newLine = "n 1" + line.Substring(colon);
            else if (ln.StartsWith("v")) newLine = "v 1" + line.Substring(colon);
        }
        else
        {
            newLine = line;
        }

        yield return newLine.Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? What is wrong with my answer? Any suggestions to improve?

Comment: Not my DV, but method should take an enumerable, not a string.

Answer (score 3):

```
var trimmedStrings = untrimmedStrings.Select(untrimmed => untrimmed.Trim());
```

to apply this to your code above,

```
var trimmedLines = text.Select(untrimmed => untrimmed.TrimStart(' '));
```

But for improved readability I would put the whole thing in a function with a name that says what you're doing. That makes the main method shorter, and when you read it the function name behaves like a comment.

```
string ConvertToSomeOtherString(string input) //don't use this name.
{
    var newLine = "";
    var ln = input.TrimStart(' ');
    var colon = input.IndexOf(":");
    if (colon != -1)
    {
        if (ln.StartsWith("adj")) newLine = "j 1" + input.Substring(colon);
        else if (ln.StartsWith("adv")) newLine = "d 1" + input.Substring(colon);
        else if (ln.StartsWith("n")) newLine = "n 1" + input.Substring(colon);
        else if (ln.StartsWith("v")) newLine = "v 1" + input.Substring(colon);
    }
    else
    {
        newLine = input;
    }
    return newLine.Trim();
}
```

Now the existing method will look like this:

```
var convertedStrings = text.Select(line => ConvertToSomeOtherString(line));
```

Before if someone reads this they can see that you're doing a bunch of things with this string, but what is it doing with the string and why? Now they read the main method and the function name says what you're doing. And if they don't care about the details of that transformation they can just keep reading. They only need to go into that function if they care about what it's doing.

---

I refactored a little, just to see what it might look like.

```
string ConvertToSomeOtherString(string input) //don't use this name.
{
    var colonPosition = input.IndexOf(":");
    if (colonPosition == -1) return input.Trim();
    var prefix = GetPrefix(input);
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) 
        ? string.Empty 
        : (prefix + input.Substring(colonPosition)).Trim();
}

string GetPrefix(string input) //Again, perhaps not the best name - I don't know what these are.
{
    var trimmed = input.TrimStart(' ');
    if (trimmed.StartsWith("adj")) return "j 1";
    if (trimmed.StartsWith("adv")) return "d 1";
    if (trimmed.StartsWith("n")) return "n 1" ;
    if (trimmed.StartsWith("v")) return "v 1" ;
    return null;
}
```